# How can I convert text inside of a TextView to NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, textview

How can I convert text in a TextView to NSString?

```
NSString *path = tabels.text;
NSData *dataFromPath = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

if(printController && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:dataFromPath]) {

    printController.delegate = self;

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = [path lastPathComponent];
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    printController.printInfo = printInfo;
    printController.showsPageRange = YES;
    printController.printingItem = dataFromPath;

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error) {
            NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, error.code);
        }
    };

    [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access the text inside of a `UITextView` using the `text` property. For example:

```
NSString *myText = aTextView.text;
```

Comment: @Rafael - If you don't mind, please give a more thorough description of your problem. I had no way of knowing that your question has anything to do with AirPrint. If you post the code you have, and explain what the trouble is, and I'll be glad to try and assist you. :-)

Comment: Try using `NSLog(@"%@", tabels.text);` to see if your text is getting properly assigned as you want it to be.

Comment: Maybe you did forget to bind the actual TextView to the IBOutlet?